# Need to do union all in Hive on all table names coming from python list

Tags: python, hive

I have n number of tables names coming in a python list like this:

**tb_name = ['table A1', 'table A2', 'table A3', ....., 'table An']**

Is there a way in Hive QL (using explode, lateral view etc) to create a Hive query like:

```
Select *
From table A1
UNION ALL
Select *
From table A2
UNION ALL
Select *
From table A3
UNION ALL
.
.
Select *
From table An
```

I can use python3 to read from list and create query in string format first and then pass it to Hive to run it though using below code:

```
query = "Select * From {} ".format(tb_name[0])
for t in tb_name:
    if t != tb_name[0]
        query = query + " UNION ALL Select * From {} ".format(t)
```

But I am just looking for a way to handle this list of table names in Hive itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following, assuming that the 'tb_name' list is passed as a comma-separated string. For example: tb_name = 'table A1,table A2,table A3,...,table An'

```
SET hivevar:table_names='table A1,table A2,table A3,...,table An';
SELECT split('${hivevar:table_names}', ',') AS table_name_array;
SET hivevar:table_names='table A1,table A2,table A3,...,table An';
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name) AS hive_query
FROM (SELECT explode(split('${hivevar:table_names}', ',')) AS table_name) t;
SET hivevar:table_names='table A1,table A2,table A3,...,table An';
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name) AS hive_query
FROM (SELECT explode(split('${hivevar:table_names}', ',')) AS table_name) t
JOIN ${hivevar:table_name} 
ON 1=1;
```